# Spark sqlContext select all

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I read data using Spark SQLContext and store it on a variable:

```
 val somevar = sqlContext.read.parquet(some_file.parquet)
```

Then I wish to select all the values using select, something like:

```
  somevar.select(*)
```

But this does not work.

The equivalent would be to do:

```
somevar.registerTempTable("sometable")

sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM sometable")
```

But I do not wish to do the previous.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a syntax error. The following syntax is how you ***select all*** columns with spark-sql :

```
import sqlContext.implicit._

val df = Seq((1,2),(2,3)).toDF
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int]

// solution 1
df.select("*")
// res54: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int]

// alternative 1
df.select($"*")
// res55: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int]

// alternative 2
df.select('*)
// res56: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: int, _2: int]
```